# How do I earn interest at the Automatic Bell Dispenser?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have been told the ABD actually gives out some interest based on how many bells you put in, but it's not every day. What % of interest do I get and how do I claim it? Do I have to play every day for it to count or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Post+Office):

> > On the first day of the month, you receive interest on your Savings at the rate of 0.5% per month, subject to a maximum interest of 99,999 bells.

So you do not get interest until the month change.

Comment: So if I maximize my account at the end of the month…